# Не складываются разные типы

Tags: php

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, почему у  меня не складываются две переменные разных типов? PHP же не строго типизированный язык, что я делаю не так?

```
<?php

$a = "a";
$b = 21;

function sum(&$a, &$b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}

echo sum($a, $b);

?>
```

Comment: Первый операнд строка, для сложения строк используется оператор  .

Comment: Сможете показать на примере?

Comment: сложение это арифметическая операция. операнды если могут, то приводятся к целому числу. Согласно правилам приведения типов, строка "а" приводится к 0, поскольку не начинается с цифр. Так что, если на выходе у вас 21, то все у вас исправно складывается с учетом терминологии и языка.

Comment: Если складывать будете не "а" а "10а", то получите 31. А если `"20" + 21` то 41

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = "a";
$b = 21;

function sum(&$a, &$b)
{
   return $a . $b;
}

echo sum($a, $b);

?>
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/KH4MmQsCDuw 8:05 почему здесь у автора всё работает?

Comment: У него первый операнд число

Comment: А у меня второй операнд число 0_о

Comment: Всё, я понял)))